# SQL identifier must be declared even declared already

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm running the attached query but having the error

error(1,41):PLS-00201:identifier 'TABLE_OUTPUT' must be declared.

How can I fix this? I'm already to replace and change here and there but... It should be OK right?

Checking the parameter, I'm sure that I've already put the right type and match...

Thanks!

```
create OR REPLACE procedure proc_gen_data (TBL_OUTPUT OUT TABLE_OUTPUT)
is
    TYPE REC_OUTPUT IS RECORD( 
     eorder_date DATE,
         entity_bic11 VARCHAR2(20),
         entity_bic11 VARCHAR2(20),
         ACCOUNT VARCHAR2(100),
         COVERED_BY VARCHAR2(20),
         ENTITIES_PRIORITIES VARCHAR2(1),
         TASK_PRIORITY VARCHAR2(5),
         folder_published NUMBER,
         NEW_STATUS VARCHAR2(10)
         );

  TYPE TABLE_OUTPUT IS TABLE OF REC_OUTPUT;
  LC_SELECT SYS_REFCURSOR;
  LR_DETAILS TABLE_OUTPUT;
begin
    OPEN LC_SELECT FOR
            select   t2.EORDER_DATE "EORDER DATE", t1.bic11 "ENTITY BIC11", t2.ACCOUNT, t2.covered_by "COVERED BY", t2.entities_priorities "ENTITIES PRIORITY", t1.top_priority "TASK PRIORITY", t2.folder_published "FOLDERS PUBLISHED", T2.NEW_STATUS "NEW STATUS"
            from
            (select s.entity_group_name entity_name, s.bic11 bic11,
            --to_char(MAX(IOCUPDATED),'DD-MON-YYYY') "IOC_LAST_UPDATE",
            --to_char(MAX(OMSUPDATED),'DD-MON-YYYY') "OMS_LAST_UPDATE",
            --to_char(MAX(TOBUPDATED),'DD-MON-YYYY') "TOB_LAST_UPDATE",
            --to_char(MAX(COMUPDATED),'DD-MON-YYYY') "COM_LAST_UPDATE",
            --(MAX(TAXUPDATED),'DD-MON-YYYY') "TAX_LAST_UPDATE",
              CASE 
                    WHEN MAX(IOCUPDATED) >= MAX(OMSUPDATED) AND MAX(IOCUPDATED) >= MAX(TOBUPDATED) AND MAX(IOCUPDATED) >= MAX(COMUPDATED) AND MAX(IOCUPDATED) >= MAX(TAXUPDATED) THEN 'IOC'
                    WHEN MAX(OMSUPDATED) >= MAX(IOCUPDATED) AND MAX(OMSUPDATED) >= MAX(TOBUPDATED) AND MAX(OMSUPDATED) >= MAX(COMUPDATED) AND MAX(OMSUPDATED) >= MAX(TAXUPDATED) THEN 'OMS'
                    WHEN MAX(TOBUPDATED) >= MAX(IOCUPDATED) AND MAX(TOBUPDATED) >= MAX(OMSUPDATED) AND MAX(TOBUPDATED) >= MAX(COMUPDATED) AND MAX(TOBUPDATED) >= MAX(TAXUPDATED) THEN 'TOB'
                    WHEN MAX(COMUPDATED) >= MAX(IOCUPDATED) AND MAX(COMUPDATED) >= MAX(OMSUPDATED) AND MAX(COMUPDATED) >= MAX(TOBUPDATED) AND MAX(COMUPDATED) >= MAX(TAXUPDATED) THEN 'COM'                    
                    WHEN MAX(TAXUPDATED) >= MAX(IOCUPDATED) AND MAX(TAXUPDATED) >= MAX(OMSUPDATED) AND MAX(TAXUPDATED) >= MAX(TOBUPDATED) AND MAX(TAXUPDATED) >= MAX(COMUPDATED) THEN 'TAX'
                    ELSE    'IOC'
              END AS TOP_PRIORITY
            from
            (
                      select egr.name entity_group_name, decode(e.office_type,'GH',e.legal_name_lei,e.institution_name ) name, e.bic11,
                      decode(cat.acronym,'IOC',decode(initiated_by_swift,'N','C','S'),null) IOC,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'IOC',fi.creation_date,null) IOCCREATED,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'IOC',fis.update_date,null) IOCUPDATED,
                      decode(cat.acronym,'OMS',decode(initiated_by_swift,'N','C','S'),null) OMS,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'OMS',fi.creation_date,null) OMSCREATED,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'OMS',fis.update_date,null) OMSUPDATED,
                      decode(cat.acronym,'TOB',decode(initiated_by_swift,'N','C','S'),null) TOB,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'TOB',fi.creation_date,null) TOBCREATED,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'TOB',fis.update_date,null) TOBUPDATED,
                      decode(cat.acronym,'COM',decode(initiated_by_swift,'N','C','S'),null) COM,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'COM',fi.creation_date,null) COMCREATED,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'COM',fis.update_date,null) COMUPDATED,
                      decode(cat.acronym,'TAX',decode(initiated_by_swift,'N','C','S'),null) TAX,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'TAX',fi.creation_date,null) TAXCREATED,
                                 decode(cat.acronym,'TAX',fis.update_date,NULL) TAXUPDATED,
                      1 TOTAL
                      from entity_groups egr, entities e, folders f, folder_items fi, categories cat, folder_item_snapshots fis
                      where fi.fold_id=f.id
                         and f.enti_id =e.id
                         and e.engr_id=egr.id
                         and f.cate_id=cat.id
                --       and fi.status!='PUBLISHED'
                         and fi.id =f.foit_rece_id
                         and fis.foit_id=fi.id
                         and fi.active_snap_id=fis.id
            ) s
            group by s.entity_group_name, s.name, s.bic11
            order by s.entity_group_name, s.bic11) t1
            left join
            --STATUS REPORT
            (select to_char(creation_date, 'DD-Mon-RR') EORDER_DATE, bic11 "ENTITY_BIC11", institution_name ACCOUNT, covered COVERED_BY, 
              CASE WHEN nvl(total,0)=5 THEN '-' 
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=4 THEN 'HIGH'
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=3 THEN 'MEDIUM'
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=2 THEN 'LOW'
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=1 THEN 'LOW'
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=0 THEN 'LOW'
            END AS ENTITIES_PRIORITIES,
            nvl(total,0) FOLDER_PUBLISHED, 
              CASE WHEN nvl(total,0)=5 THEN 'COMPLETE' 
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=4 THEN 'FOLLOW UP ONGOING'
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=3 THEN 'FOLLOW UP ONGOING'
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=2 THEN 'FOLLOW UP ONGOING'
                     WHEN nvl(total,0)=1 THEN 'FOLLOW UP ONGOING'
              END AS NEW_STATUS
            from (
            select creation_date, bic11, name, institution_name, covered, entity_group_name, sum(IOC) IOC, sum(OMS) OMS, sum(TOB) TOB, sum(COM) COM, sum(TAX) TAX, sum(total) TOTAL from
            (
            select e.creation_date, e.bic11, e.name, e.institution_name, E.covered, egr.name entity_group_name, decode(cat.acronym,'IOC',1,0) IOC, decode(cat.acronym,'OMS',1,0) OMS, decode(cat.acronym,'TOB',1,0) TOB, decode(cat.acronym,'COM',1,0) COM, decode(cat.acronym,'TAX',1,0) TAX, 1 total
            from entity_groups egr, entities e, folders f, folder_items fi, categories cat, folder_item_snapshots fis
            where fi.fold_id=f.id
              and f.enti_id=e.id
              and e.engr_id=egr.id
              and f.cate_id=cat.id
             -- and fi.status = 'PUBLISHED'
              and fi.id=f.foit_rece_id
             -- and e.deletion_date is null
              and fis.foit_id=fi.id
              and fi.active_snap_id=fis.id
              )
              group by creation_date, bic11, name, entity_group_name, institution_name, covered) s,
              (select name entity_group_name from entity_groups) g
            where s.entity_group_name(+)=g.entity_group_name) t2
            on t1.bic11=t2.ENTITY_BIC11;

    LOOP
        FETCH LC_SELECT INTO LR_DETAILS;
        EXIT WHEN LC_SELECT%NOTFOUND;
        TABLE_OUTPUT.extend();
        TABLE_OUTPUT(TABLE_OUTPUT.count()) := LR_DETAILS;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE LC_SELECT;
    TABLE_OUTPUT := TABLE_OUTPUT;

END;
```

Comment: You cannot refer to a type for a procedure argument that is defined within the procedure. The type has to be declared externally to the procedure.

Comment: @jeff6times7 which part actually should I change?

Comment: Try [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjplsql.htm#ADOBJ070). You get a pass on this once only and only because your avatar is cool.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `TYPE` outside the procedure as schema objects.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  REC_OUTPUT AS  OBJECT( 
     eorder_date DATE,
         entity_bic11 VARCHAR2(20),
         ACCOUNT VARCHAR2(100),
         COVERED_BY VARCHAR2(20),
         ENTITIES_PRIORITIES VARCHAR2(1),
         TASK_PRIORITY VARCHAR2(5),
         folder_published NUMBER,
         NEW_STATUS VARCHAR2(10)
         );

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TABLE_OUTPUT IS TABLE OF REC_OUTPUT;
```

So, inside your procedure, start from this line after `DECLARE`

```
LC_SELECT SYS_REFCURSOR;
...
...
```

In your loops, you are wrongly using `TYPE` name `TABLE_OUTPUT` instead of the `TYPE` variable `TBL_OUTPUT` which is your `OUT` parameter. Use it correctly.